# A massive puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the answer to this puzzle?**

---

```
                              NPFAIMCHOLIRSTUE
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> CONTINENTS

> If we fill the square grid with the sixteen letters in natural order we have:
>
> ```
>  N P F A
>  I M C H
>  O L I R
>  S T U E
> ```

> If we then superimpose the paths onto the grid, and follow the line starting/finishing on the red dot(s) we get the following:
>  AFRI**C**A
>  A**N**TARTICA (assume this is a simple typo for Antarctica)
>  A**SI**A
>  AUS**T**RALIA
>  EUR**O**PE
>  **N**OR**T**H AMERICA
>  SOUTH AM**E**RICA

> Now we use the numbers in parentheses to take the Nth letter of each word (highlighted above), we get:
>  C N N I S T O T N E
>
>  And finally, ordering by the superscript numbers gives us the solution:
>  CONTINENTS
>
>  And of course, the words found in the grid are themselves the seven continents.

Comment: Indeed it is. Good job!